# Insert underscore every 3 count or a char in sybase

Tags: sybase

I do have a problem to solve with, i need to insert underscore for every 3 char

> Sample:
> From -> 123456789
> to -> 123_456_789

Comment: which Sybae RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? what (code) have you tried so far? does `1234` become `123_4`? is this data in a column or variable? are you looking to do this once or for a large volume of data? do you need to **update** a current column with the new value and if so, what happens if the column datatype is not large enough to contain the new underscores?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a "self-defined" function in the database that you can reuse wherever you want, be it in a query or a trigger. This is a quick and dirty example that works on my **SQL Anywhere v17** database. Depending on what "sybase" database you use you might have to adjust it or use different built-in functions (consult your reference - the Sybase docs clearly state which built-in functions are available). For simplicity I simply used a VARCHAR(100):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FormatPositionedUnderscores(par_input VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

  DECLARE ls_formatted VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE li_length INTEGER;
  DECLARE li_current INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE ls_current_char CHAR(1);

  -- trim it and calculate the length of the string
  SET par_input = TRIM(par_input);
  SET li_length = CHAR_LENGTH(par_input);

  -- iterate over every character
  WHILE li_current < li_length LOOP
    SET li_current = li_current + 1;
    -- get the current character
    SET ls_current_char = SUBSTRING(par_input, li_current, 1);
    -- append it to the resulting string
    SET ls_formatted = ls_formatted || ls_current_char;
    -- if we have 3 characters "full" (and are not at the end)
    -- append an underscore
    IF MOD(li_current, 3) = 0 AND li_current < li_length THEN
      SET ls_formatted = ls_formatted || '_';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  -- return the resulting string
  RETURN ls_formatted;

END;
```

In a query use `SELECT FormatPositionedUnderscores('123456789)` and you'll get `123_456_789`.